JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0x80
JNI method NewStringUTF expects input as a modified UTF8 string, the difference between Standard UTF-8 and modified UTF-8 is in how it handles the null (U+0000) character. In standard UTF-8, the null character is encoded as a single byte (0x00). However, in Modified UTF-8, the null character is encoded using two bytes (0xC0 0x80). Link
but when I'm trying to pass a string ending with the null character encoded using two bytes 0xC0 0x80. I'm getting error in NewStringUTF method:

Thus, It seems an extra <0x80> is getting added at the end and the method is not able to recognise last three characters.
However, When I'm passing a standard UTF8 encoded string i.e. a string ending with the null character as a single byte (0x00) to NewStringUTF method it is not giving any error. I'm not able to figure out reason behind this behaviour.
Moreover, the JNI method GetStringUTFChars is supposed to return a pointer to a modified UTF-8 string, but when I'm printing each character of returned string I'm again getting a string ending with the null character as a single byte (0x00), i.e. Standard UTF8 string.
Could someone explain why NewStringUTF method is not throwing any error when a Standard UTF8 string is passed as input however it's throwing error when I'm trying to pass a Modified UTF8 encoded string.
Also, why GetStringUTFChars method is return a Standard UTF8 string, when it's mentioned in the docs that it is supposed to return a Modified UTF8 string.
code to create a modified UTF8 string:
void TWString::PrivateEncodeJNIUTF8 (TChar8 * pDest, const TChar32 * pString, TUInt32 & pMaxBytes) noexcept
{
    TRACEFUNC;

    TUInt32     i;
    TUInt32     destbytes;
    TChar8 *    dest;

i         = 0;
dest      = pDest;
destbytes = 0;

while (pString[i]) {

    if (pString[i] < 128) {

        *dest = (TUInt8) pString[i];
        ++dest;
        destbytes += 1;

    } else if ((pString[i] >= 128) && (pString[i] < 2048)) {

        *(TUInt16 *) ((VPtr) dest) = PrivateEncode2ByteUTF8 (pString[i]);
        dest = dest + 2;
        destbytes += 2;

    } else if ((pString[i] >= 2048) && (pString[i] < 65536)) {

        *(TUInt32 *) ((VPtr) dest) = PrivateEncode3ByteUTF8 (pString[i]);
        dest = dest + 3;
        destbytes += 3;

    } else if ((pString[i] >= 65536) && (pString[i] < 1114111)) {        // utf16, 4 byte range

        *(TUInt32 *) ((VPtr) dest) = PrivateEncode4ByteUTF16 (pString[i]);
        dest = dest + 4;
        destbytes += 4;

    } else {

        // CHECKTRUE (true);

        // TODO: Is this right?

        *(TUInt32 *) ((VPtr) dest) = (TUInt32) (pString[i]);
        dest = dest + 4;
        destbytes += 4;
    }

    ++i;
}

*dest       = TWConst (TWString)::sTWNullCharMUTF8Byte1;
*(dest + 1) = TWConst (TWString)::sTWNullCharMUTF8Byte2;

destbytes += 2;        // Null char is of 2 bytes
pMaxBytes = destbytes;
}

where:
static constexpr TUInt8 sTWNullCharMUTF8Byte1  = 192;   // decimal value of 0xc0
static constexpr TUInt8 sTWNullCharMUTF8Byte2  = 128;   // decimal value of 0x80


What version of Android are you testing this on? also, show the exact NewStringUTF call you are trying.

The log is a direct dump of the bytes you passed in so the extra 0x80 is coming from your end somehow.

You need to post your code.

As for your last question: this code explains what GetStringUTFChars returns. It's not quite modified UTF8 but they do respect the two-byte encoding of NUL.

@AndrewHenle have added the code to get modified UTF8

@botje, any idea why NewStringUTF doesn't throw any error when I pass a standard UTF8 string, i.e. null character as a single byte (0x00)

Because that is interpreted as the end of the input string and nothing after it is read. That was the whole motivation for modified UTF-8!

Also, looking at your code, you forgot to add the  final NUL terminator after your c0 80 pair. That may very well explain the extra 0x80.

Finally, your code is itself incapable of handling embedded NUL bytes since you do not take an explicit length argument.

@botje, So you mean to get a modified UTF8 string I have to add 0xc0 0x80 0x00 at the end of the string? but isn't the link I pasted in the ques state that The null byte '\u0000' is encoded in 2-byte format i.e. 0xc0 0x80 rather than 1-byte 0x00

Is it possible you are mixing up the use of NUL (0x00) as string terminator and NULs embedded in the middle of the string? A string in modified UTF-8 encoding still needs a string terminator so the consumer knows when to stop reading, and only embedded NULs will be represented as c0 80 pairs.

I think yes, I have mixed it up. so, to be clear a string "Hello\0World" when converted to modified UTF-8 will be "Hello 0xc0 0x80 World"i.e. it will still end will a null character only, right?

That is correct.

Just FYI: "the difference between Standard UTF-8 and modified UTF-8 is in how it handles the null (U+0000) character" - that is not the only difference. Modified UTF-8 also doesn't allow Unicode codepoints above U+FFFF to be in standard UTF-8 4-byte form, but instead they have to be encoded as UTF-16 surrogate pairs in 3-byte UTF-8 form. This is explained in Java's documenatiom: Modified UTF-8

@RemyLebeau While true in general, I point you to this line in the Android code with the wonderful comment "this is against the JNI spec"
